# Fluid Query Result object to JSON

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have a result object in my view and want do put this in JSON format.

The Object looks like

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResultprototypeobject (32 items)
0 => KN\Operations\Domain\Model\Operationprototypepersistent entity (uid=853, 
pid=90)
1 => KN\Operations\Domain\Model\Operationprototypepersistent entity (uid=852, 
pid=90)
....
```

I tried to use format

```
{myObject-> f:format.json()}
```

but this doesn't work. Result is

```
{}
```

I want to give that informations to my JS. For me it is not possible to change the Controller because I don't want to change an existing extension.

Comment: Try a look at here: https://usetypo3.com/json-view.html

Answer (score -1):

the format.json viewhelper expects an array as the value. To get the right result you need to convert your result into an array.
If you set the first param of the execute function in your repository to true you will get an array instead of an Queryresult Object.

```
return $query->execute(true);
```

You can find additional information on the documentation page of the viewhelper: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Format/Json.html

Happy Coding!